# Is it possible to have different contour ranges for contourf?

Tags: matlab, contour

I have bathymetry data with values ranging from -7000 to 0. Is it possible to contour different value ranges in a single image? Example: range from -100 to 10, -1000 to -100, -5000 to -1000 and -7000 to -5000 in a single `contourf` plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is – just specify a vector in the second argument, e.g.:

```
Z = peaks;
contourf(Z,[-10 -5 -1 0 1 5 10]);
```

You can even use `Inf` and `-Inf` at the to extremes to make sure that you capture the extrema (or `min(Z(:))` and `max(Z(:))`).

In your case, use `[-7000 -5000 -1000 -100 10]` as the second vector to get the ranges that you want. Not sure why you want to go to `+10` when you said the range of data only goes to `0`...

Comment: The documentation specifies that the second argument, `V`, must be monotonically increasing. However, in current versions at least, `contourf` appears to sort it anyways.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. There was a typo there. It was meant to be -10 instead of 10.